# Whether I should write, simple join for common records?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application. I have two queries I want to get common records from those queries.

Am I suppose to write simple join to get the common records ?

```
 var poList = 
   (from po in db.PurchaseOrders
    where po.CompanyId == companyId && 
          po.PartyId == partyId && 
         (po.IsDeleted == false || po.IsDeleted == null)
    select po into newPO
    select new
    {
        Name = newPO.PONo,
        Id = newPO.Id    
    }); 

var poList2 = (db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == EmpID)
      .SelectMany(x => x.Roles)
      .SelectMany(x => x.Employees)
      .Distinct()
      .SelectMany(x => x.PurchaseOrders)
      .Select(po => new { Name = po.PONo, Id = po.Id }));
```

I am trying to write the join but its asking for one more argument, how to write a simple join for common records ?

```
  var finalPO = poList.Join(poList2).ToList();
```

Comment: What's the use of `.SelectMany(x => x.Roles).SelectMany(x => x.Employees)`? You don't use the entities in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Union will give you all records from both:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx

Join method will give you records that match on provided key, but requires more than just the two enumerables as parameters: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx

Comment: I want to get the common records from these two quries, so should I use union or join ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread, union would give you superset including records from both, Join is what you want but you need more parameters, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use an overload of Join method to specify join conditions:

poList.Join(poList2, a => a.Name, b => b.Name, (a,b) => new { Name = b.PONo, Id = b.Id });

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a join because you can apply the expressions in the first query to the "raw" result of the second one:

```
var poList2 = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == EmpID)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Roles)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Employees)
                .Distinct()
                .SelectMany(x => x.PurchaseOrders);

var result = from po in poList2
             where po.CompanyId == companyId && 
                   po.PartyId == partyId && 
                   !po.IsDeleted
             select po into newPO
             select new
             {
                 Name = newPO.PONo,
                 Id = newPO.Id    
             };
```

And if you need the result you originally intended to get from `poList2`:

```
var result2 = poList2.Select(po => 
              {
                  Name = po.PONo,
                  Id = po.Id    
              };
```

So, generally speaking, you can do more with your query bodies if you postpone the projection to anonymous types.

Side note: I used `!po.IsDeleted` because I'd strongly recommend to make the field not nullable, with `false` as default value.